# Java Program Won't Run Due to JRE Version

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, version

*I'll premise by saying I am new to Java*

I'm trying to run a program in Eclipse. I really haven't done much at all in terms of building the program, I pretty much just added a GUI using JFrame by following a Youtube video.

My problem is that I'm getting this error whenever I try and run the program:

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
**Build path specifies execution environment JavaSE-14. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment**.  Calculator      Build path  JRE System Library Problem

I'm running SE-15. How should I fix this?

Comment: I think that is usually just a warning. Is it actually stopping the program from running?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you installed the latest version, 2020-09, along with Java 15.

It's useful to know that Eclipse can run with a particular version of Java, even while your applications run in Eclipse with a different version of Java.

You have provided Java 15 to run Eclipse with, and that is what Eclipse assumes it will run applications with, by default.

However, at this point in time, the support in Eclipse for features that are new to Java 15 is experimental.  There is an additional plugin you can install that will unlock the Java 15 features, although you probably don't need those yet.

Because the Java 15 features are disabled by default, it's using the execution environment of "JavaSE-14", but you don't have a Java distribution that is strictly compatible with that interface.

As a commenter pointed out, this is only a warning, so it's not likely actually causing a problem.  You could likely get by ignoring this warning and focusing on the real errors in your application.

However, addressing the warning could be done in two different ways:

- Install a distribution of Java 14, add it to the "Installed JREs" list, and edit the "Execution Environment" for Java 14 to refer to the Java 14 installation
- Install the plugin that enables Java 15 features (I haven't done this), and ensure that the project uses the "JavaSE-15" execution environment (install the plugin from the "Marketplace Client", entering "Java 15" in the search field)